# Mail domain hosted with someone else, can't send mail from server with www hosted domain

Tags: linux, email

I have a site on one machine with the domain name www.example.com. The email domain is handled by someone else. When I try to send a mail from a php script on the website hosted by my machine to bob@example.com. the mail logs says there is relaylock.

```
relaylock: /var/qmail/bin/relaylock: mail from 127.0.0.1:57672 (localhost)
```

It is only caused by rcpts with the same domain name @example.com. Anyone know what I can do to resolve this?

Thanks

--M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email was switched on for the virtualhost. All email were looking for the mailbox locally. I switched off email for the domain, and they are nowing being sent.

Answer (score 0):

A quick google shows [this site](http://www.atomicrocketturtle.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=8626&sid=95c9457f1b7df5c4c5aa6b50b7d52793) with what looked at first glance to be someone with a similar problem. Does it fix your issue?

It sounds like your qmail system thinks it's spam. Is qmail set up to allow that email domain to relay through it?

Comment: Your www machine is the one with the relaylock, or your email at the mailmachine? Are they in two different domains and you're trying to send from www through mailmachine, or send mail to someone else on mailmachine? Or are you saying that you're sending mail on www through qmail on your www machine to another host and getting the error?

Comment: Im sending mail on www (server1,domain1) through qmail (server1,domain1) on same machine to another host (server2,domain2) and its refusing to send from (server1,domain1).

Comment: Also, there is a rcpt hosts file in qmail/control and it has my domain listed. Would that be the cause?

Comment: Could be...does this link (http://www.palomine.net/qmail/relaying.html) have information that helps you with setting it up to allow relaying? I know qmail needs the information to know what it's authorized to send mail on behalf of.

Answer (score 0):

relaylock isn't a standard part of qmail; a quick google shows it's this add on: [smtp-popblock](http://www.davideous.com/smtp-poplock/), the purpose of which seems to be POP-before-SMTP authentication for qmail (instead of implementing pure SMTPAUTH).

Reading between the lines, it looks like that (for whatever reason), qmail's been set-up not to allow any outgoing mail that's come in over SMTP. If your able to change your app so it injects into the mail queue using 'sendmail', then that would be a possible work-around.

Whether your web-host thinks that's valid is another question entirely :-) You may need to specify an alternate SMTP server. You've not said who controls the web-server, but if it's not yours, then they may have locked mail services down for specific apps - and they'll have a different server to handle SMTP requests.